# Why do my Mariadb characters get mangled on the return leg of my query?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mariadb, utf8mb4

I have non-ASCII characters in keys in my database that are supposed to be UTF-8 (`utf8mb4`) encoded. And they sort of are, but not entirely:

From Java via JDBC (`mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.21`), a:

```
SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE id="Dümmer";
```

produces the right row. However, the value of the `id` column is returned as:

```
DÃ¼mmer
```

Here is what I know:

- in the `mysql` console, the value is printed correctly.
- the column has been created with:

  ```
  `id` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_nopad_bin NOT NULL,
  ```
- the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource` has a `null` character encoding. I have tried `.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" )` but that does not seem to make a difference.

Where else should I look? This is Linux, Mariadb 10.5.5, running client and server on the same machine.

Comment: In what context is it 'returned'. It looks like a bunch of UTF-8 bytes, but rendered in a place that thinks it's latin-1. How/where are you looking at the output?

Comment: I'm looking at it straight after the JDBC API call in the debugger, because my sanity check (`idInQuery.equals(idReceivedFromQuery)`) balked at me.

Comment: Where is your debugger running? In a terminal? What encoding does it use? Possibly run `echo $LANG`

Comment: It's not a debugger problem. I have both `idInQuery` and `idReceivedFromQuery` right next to each other in various places (debugger, my app) and they differ.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a problem, I'm saying it might use a different encoding. Even if the first one 'looks right', it could still be in in `ISO-8559-1` encoding and your input could be wrong. Understanding whether your input or output is wrong is valuable to debug this.

Comment: I'm now single-stepping through the mysql connector, and it appears that the server represents the `id` column as "binary", which then is mapped by the connector to the first encoding that it knows of, which happens to be ISO-8859-1. I can't claim I understand why it might be doing either, but decoding my UTF-8 string as ISO-8859-1 would explain what I'm seeing. (Stopping my investigation here, time for a workaround.)